# Redirect page after SQL query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Assuming that I'm on http://localhost:7924/default , and I type the login info , here is what happens in each scenario :

> 1. If password is wrong (or correct) + login_name doesn't exist => **refresh page**
> 2. If password is wrong + login_name exist (correct) => going to
>      **error_page**
> 3. If both are correct => redirected to **CP.aspx**

```
  string text = username_login.Text;
    string str2 = password_login.Text;
    SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(Functions.Auth());
    SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
    sqlcmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 password FROM dbo.Accounts WHERE login_name = @login_name";
    sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@login_name", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = text;
    sqlcmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    sqlcmd.Connection = sqlcon;
    sqlcon.Open();
    SqlDataReader sqlreader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
    string returnString = String.Empty;
    while (sqlreader.Read())
    {


       if  (sqlreader["password"].ToString() == Functions.CreateMD5Hash("5487" + str2.ToString()))
        {
            this.Session["logged_in"] = "true";
            this.Session["username"] = text;
            base.Response.Redirect("/CP.aspx");

        }
        else

        {
            base.Response.Redirect("/error_page?err=login-fail");
        }

    }
```

Both **2.** & **3.** are working as should be, however, the first one is not. I don't understand why It only refreshes the page instead of going to the error page since the details are wrong. (since It cannot make the comparison)

**EDIT :** I also checked if password is NULL => redirect to error_page but that refreshes the page as well.

Comment: When the login_name does not exist, the execution will not go into the while loop (since sqlreader.Read() will return false), so it just renders the same page again

Comment: @Thangadurai I got it fixed by checking if the Sqlreader.Read() is false after the else statement. thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to check if it has any value.

```
if(sqlreader.HasRows)
{
    While...
}
else
{
   //refresh page code here
}
```

Also you might want to think about a better architect n-tie, Presentation Layer, Business Layer, Data Access Layer.

Answer (score 1):

Technically: 1. if `sqlreader` hasn't any row or 2. if none of conditions in `while loop` getting `true`, the same page would be rendered. But for getting referesh the page, you can use `Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)`. I like to make some changes in your code - just a little bit:

```
// since you are selecting 1 top row, here you would 0 or 1 row at all. 
// so you don't need to use `while` and `if` doing well
// also, you won't need to check if `sqlreader.HasRows`, 
// because the `if (sqlreader.Read())` does the same.
if (sqlreader.Read())
{


   if  (sqlreader["password"].ToString() == Functions.CreateMD5Hash("5487" + str2.ToString()))
    {
        this.Session["logged_in"] = "true";
        this.Session["username"] = text;
        base.Response.Redirect("/CP.aspx");

    }
    else

    {
        base.Response.Redirect("/error_page?err=login-fail");
    }

}
// there is no need to use an `else`. just do the redirect:
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `~` before link :

```
base.Response.Redirect("~/CP.aspx");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code and check it this will solve your problem

```
    public static string ReplaceAll(String Str)
        {
            Str = Str.Replace("'", " ");
            Str = Str.Replace(";", " ");
            Str = Str.TrimStart();
            Str = Str.TrimEnd();
            return Str;
        }
public void MyFunction()
    {
    SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(Functions.Auth());
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TOP 1 password FROM dbo.Accounts WHERE login_name = '" + ReplaceAll(username_login.Text) + "' and password='" + ReplaceAll(password_login.Text) + "'", sqlcon);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                this.Session["logged_in"] = "true";
                this.Session["username"] = text;
                base.Response.Redirect("/CP.aspx");

            }
            else
            {
                base.Response.Redirect("/error_page?err=login-fail");
            }}
```

Comment: To protect your application from SQL injection, please do not concatenate your query with value instead use SqlParameterCollection.

Comment: i am using ReplaceAll() to avoid SQL Injection

Comment: I would not recommend doing that, as you are not covering all the different type of SQL injection. One of the reason SqlParameterCollection was created is to prevent SQL Injection.